# py2neo - updating existing node with new properties w/uniqueness constraint (merge_one)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I've been trying to figure out a way to adapt the merge_one functionality from py2neo v2 to v3. I read in a [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fil#!topic/neo4j/3rvSAKPixpc) that "The merge_one method no longer exists in v3 as you should be able to use merge in all cases instead." but I can't figure out how to easily use regular merge in v3.

I'm trying to recreate [Nicole White's neo4j twitter example](http://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-jupyter/twitter.html) project with a small modification. She used merge_one. There are uniqueness constraints on (u:User) - u.username and (t:Tweet) - t.id. Her script always has the same properties for Tweet and User nodes, but I am making a case where sometimes I want to go back and add more properties to an existing node with merge. However I get the error

`py2neo.database.status.ConstraintError: Node 178 already exists with label Tweet and property "id"=[***]`

I understand this is because when I have for example a Tweet that already exists with just an id and then I try to do

```
        tw_dict = {'id'=t['id'], 'text':t['text'], 'created':t['created_at'],
               'rts':t['retweet_count'],
               'favs':t['favorite_count'], 'lang':t['lang']}
        tweet = Node("Tweet", **tw_dict)
        graph.create(tweet)
```

merge is not finding the same tweet with all those properties and when it tries to create one is running into the uniqueness constraint on Tweet's id. It looks like the merge_one function would have solved this, but it's not available in v3. So instead I've implemented the following:

```
    exists = graph.find_one("Tweet", "id", t['id'])
    if exists:
        exists['text'] = t['text']
        exists['created'] = t['created_at']
        exists['rts'] = t['retweet_count']
        exists['favs'] = t['favorite_count']
        exists['lang'] = t['lang']
    else:
        tw_dict = {'text':t['text'], 'created':t['created_at'],
               'rts':t['retweet_count'],
               'favs':t['favorite_count'], 'lang':t['lang']}
        tweet = Node("Tweet", **tw_dict)
        graph.create(tweet)
```

but this seems repetitive to me. Is there not an easier way in py2neo to do something like updating an existing node with new properties and still specifying a property with a unique constraint (in this case id)? I think in Cypher I would do a merge on just the id and then set on match or set on create but I don't see how to do that with py2neo. I also tried to find in the documentation something that would allow an update of properties from a dictionary with an existing node but can't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

py2neo v3 now has `graph.merge()`, which you can use to the same effect.

First find or create the node with `graph.merge()`, matching *only* on its unique property, then update its other non-unique properties with `node.push()`. You would've had to do the same thing with `graph.merge_one()`, just with a slightly different syntax.

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node
graph = Graph()

tweet = Node('Tweet', id=123)
graph.merge(tweet)
tweet['text'] = 'Hello World'
tweet.push()
```

I should update that twitter script to use py2neo v3; thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you could change the node's properties after merging with a push like that. Your example is really helpful for learning to use neo4j and python with Twitter by the way!

Comment: Thanks! Also, I updated the script you linked in your question to use py2neo v3.

Comment: Pushing to a node (i.e., [node].push) gives me a runtime error. I needed to use graph.push(node) instead.

Comment: I am getting an error node object has no attribut push.

Comment: use graph.push(tweet)

Answer (score 10):

Two things;

1.)
tweet.push() has been deprecated. The docs suggest using graph.push(tweet).

2.)
I am having trouble to get this working with a transaction such as:

```
transaction = graph.begin()
transaction.merge(tweet)
transaction.graph.push(tweet)
transaction.commit()
```

Any suggestion on the difference between using `graph.merge` and `transaction.merge`?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I only managed to make it work bringing the invocation of the push method out of the transaction...

Answer (score 0):

To update for py2neo v5 - 2020, you may update multiple properties for an existing node from a dictionary.

```py
from py2neo import NodeMatcher
tw_dict = {'text':t['text'], 
           'created':t['created_at'],
           'rts':t['retweet_count'],
           'favs':t['favorite_count'], 
           'lang':t['lang']}
tweet = matcher.match('Tweet', id=123).first()
if tweet:
    tweet.update(**properties)
    graph.push(tweet)
```

Comment: I think you maent  tweet.update(**tw_dict )